# Fixing overlapping values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I fix the overlapping values on the x axis?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         % multilenguaje

% grid style

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
    \node[star,star point ratio=2.25,minimum size=6pt,
    inner sep=0pt,draw=black,solid,fill=red] {};
}

\decimalpoint
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{1,0.647058823529412,0}
\begin{document}




    \begin{tikzpicture}



    \begin{axis}[
    axis line style={black},
    scaled x ticks = true,
    legend cell align={left},
    legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)}, anchor=north west, draw=black},
    tick align=outside,
    x grid style={dashed,black!60},
    xlabel={$\lambda$},
    xmajorticks=true,
    xmin=0.0055, xmax=0.1045,
    xtick style={color=black},
    y grid style={dashed,black!60},
    ylabel={RMSE},
    ymajorticks=true,
    ymin=0.912938021884183, ymax=1.01339429908853,
    ytick style={black},
    xtick align=inside,
    ytick align=inside,
    grid = none,
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=4
    },
    ]
\addplot [mark = *,line width=0.8pt,blue, mark size=1pt]
table {%
    0.01 0.97820029742643
    0.02 0.962938632883304
    0.03 0.944377590107486
    0.04 0.934490513382265
    0.05 0.926770707258887
    0.09 0.921652885011797
    0.1 0.922493653631392
};
\addlegendentry{20 f}
\addplot [mark = *,line width=0.8pt,black, mark size=1pt]
table {%
    0.01 0.992629285376604
    0.02 0.970555305088483
    0.03 0.950769057081716
    0.04 0.937408149963347
    0.05 0.92888998569171
    0.09 0.919757726792486
    0.1 0.922265347358195
};
\addlegendentry{30 f}
\addplot [mark = *,line width=0.8pt,red, mark size=1pt]
table {%
    0.01 1.00429685084556
    0.02 0.976819790163343
    0.03 0.955650609854943
    0.04 0.939869451503815
    0.05 0.927933873176105
    0.09 0.917634061468206
    0.1 0.920597626159782
};
\addlegendentry{50 f}
\addplot [mark = *,line width=0.8pt,yellow, mark size=1pt]
table {%
    0.01 1.00882810467015
    0.02 0.972771038904076
    0.03 0.955085239938932
    0.04 0.941800125612627
    0.05 0.930788565993547
    0.09 0.917504216302563
    0.1 0.920804593468368
};
\addlegendentry{100 f}
\addplot [mark = *,line width=0.8pt,orange, mark size=1pt]
table {%
    0.01 1.00130716487781
    0.02 0.97125309142477
    0.03 0.952896925523292
    0.04 0.940895422722576
    0.05 0.931374232049292
    0.09 0.920535667968586
    0.1 0.920701204441381
};
\addlegendentry{150 f}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your request; is just a pure suggestion. You should maybe replace the yellow with green. That way, it would be easier to be seen (a combination of yellow line and white background is not the best) and there will be another colour that separates the yellow, orange and red.

Comment: Great suggestion. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Scale the x-ticks

```
scaled x ticks = base 10:2,
```

[image]

#### 2. Change the number format

```
xticklabel style={
/pgf/number format/fixed,
/pgf/number format/precision=2},
```

[image]

#### 3. Reduce the number of xticks.

List only the needed xtick labels

```
xtick={0.00,0.02,...,0.12},
```

OR, increase `xtick distance` (as commented by [Stefan Pinnow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/95441/stefan-pinnow))

```
xtick distance=0.02,
```

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         % multilenguaje

% grid style

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
    \node[star,star point ratio=2.25,minimum size=6pt,
    inner sep=0pt,draw=black,solid,fill=red] {};
}

\decimalpoint
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{1,0.647058823529412,0}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis line style={black},
%    scaled x ticks = base 10:2,
%   xticklabel style={
%   /pgf/number format/fixed,
%   /pgf/number format/precision=2},
    xtick={0.00,0.02,...,0.12},
    legend cell align={left},
    legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)}, anchor=north west, draw=black},
    tick align=outside,
    x grid style={dashed,black!60},
    xlabel={$\lambda$},
    xmajorticks=true,
    xmin=0.0055, xmax=0.1045,
    xtick style={color=black},
    y grid style={dashed,black!60},
    ylabel={RMSE},
    ymajorticks=true,
    ymin=0.912938021884183, ymax=1.01339429908853,
    ytick style={black},
    xtick align=inside,
    ytick align=inside,
    grid = none,
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=4
    },
    ]
\addplot [mark = *,line width=0.8pt,blue, mark size=1pt]
table {%
    0.01 0.97820029742643
    0.02 0.962938632883304
    0.03 0.944377590107486
    0.04 0.934490513382265
    0.05 0.926770707258887
    0.09 0.921652885011797
    0.1 0.922493653631392
};
\addlegendentry{20 f}
\addplot [mark = *,line width=0.8pt,black, mark size=1pt]
table {%
    0.01 0.992629285376604
    0.02 0.970555305088483
    0.03 0.950769057081716
    0.04 0.937408149963347
    0.05 0.92888998569171
    0.09 0.919757726792486
    0.1 0.922265347358195
};
\addlegendentry{30 f}
\addplot [mark = *,line width=0.8pt,red, mark size=1pt]
table {%
    0.01 1.00429685084556
    0.02 0.976819790163343
    0.03 0.955650609854943
    0.04 0.939869451503815
    0.05 0.927933873176105
    0.09 0.917634061468206
    0.1 0.920597626159782
};
\addlegendentry{50 f}
\addplot [mark = *,line width=0.8pt,yellow, mark size=1pt]
table {%
    0.01 1.00882810467015
    0.02 0.972771038904076
    0.03 0.955085239938932
    0.04 0.941800125612627
    0.05 0.930788565993547
    0.09 0.917504216302563
    0.1 0.920804593468368
};
\addlegendentry{100 f}
\addplot [mark = *,line width=0.8pt,orange, mark size=1pt]
table {%
    0.01 1.00130716487781
    0.02 0.97125309142477
    0.03 0.952896925523292
    0.04 0.940895422722576
    0.05 0.931374232049292
    0.09 0.920535667968586
    0.1 0.920701204441381
};
\addlegendentry{150 f}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some small remarks: To 1. Stating `scaled x ticks=true` yields the same result, but is a bit easier to write. To 3. I would use `xtick distance=0.02` instead, which is much easier to write.

Comment: @StefanPinnow `xtick distance=0.02` works fine. But `scaled x ticks=true` doesn't give the same result as 1. The code given in the original post has stated `scaled x ticks=true`.

Comment: This was untested, sorry. And you are right. This is because `xmax` is greater or equal 0.1. So another alternative would be to state `scale ticks below exponent=0`, but that is not much better than your solution ...

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**
Now I notice to late that other answer has added the same solution for `xtick` labels as I try proposed :-(. So only some off-topic suggestions ...

I would design your diagram with use of the `filecontents` package and reduced number of decimal digits for `y` values to four (to my opinion they still provide satisfactory accuracy):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         % multilenguaje
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,
                positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\linewidth}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{performance.data}
x    A       B         C        D        E 
0.01 0.9782  0.99262   1.0042   1.0088   1.0013
0.02 0.9629  0.97055   0.9768   0.9727   0.9712
0.04 0.9344  0.93740   0.9398   0.9418   0.9408
0.05 0.9267  0.92888   0.9279   0.9307   0.9313
0.09 0.9216  0.91975   0.9176   0.9175   0.9205
0.1  0.9224  0.92226   0.9205   0.9208   0.9207
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid = none,
    legend style={font=\small},
    legend cell align=left,         
    legend pos=north east,
    xmin=0.005, xmax=0.105,
    ylabel={RMSE},
    xlabel={$\lambda$},
%
xticklabel style={font=\small,
    /pgf/number format/fixed},  
yticklabel style={font=\small},
%
every axis plot post/.append style={line width=0.8pt},
%
mark size=1pt,
cycle list={
    {blue,mark=*},
    {black,mark=*},
    {red,mark=*},
    {yellow,mark=*},
    {orange,mark=otimes*}% <-- don't add a comma here
            },
    ]
\addplot    table [y=A] {performance.data};
\addlegendentry{20 f}
\addplot    table [y=B] {performance.data};
\addlegendentry{30 f}
\addplot    table [y=C] {performance.data};
\addlegendentry{50 f}
\addplot    table [y=D] {performance.data};
\addlegendentry{100 f}
\addplot    table [y=E] {performance.data};
\addlegendentry{150 f}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like your approach! Thank you very much! The only thing is that I have to write down the values and cannot use libreoffice or some tool like those. How did you do it, meaning the `performance.data` file?

Comment: @Delan, I do not know, how you generate data. However on the same way as you form tables in your question, you can compose one table from them as I do in my answer.